# Python check newest image in file

Tags: python, python-3.x, operating-system, os.path, listdir

I need to get the latest image file inside a folder, here's what i've tried :

```
import os.path
import os

path = 'C:/Users/William/Desktop/Test Utk Deploy/Image Dir'

if len(os.listdir(path) ) == 0:
    print("Directory is empty")
else:
    files = []
    for file in os.listdir(path):
        if file.endswith(".png") or file.endswith(".jpg") or file.endswith(".jpeg") or file.endswith(".PNG") or file.endswith(".JPG") or file.endswith(".JPEG"):
            files.append(file)
    print(max(files , key = os.path.getctime))
```

however, i got this error

```
runfile('C:/Users/William/Desktop/Test Utk Deploy/deploy.py', wdir='C:/Users/William/Desktop/Test Utk Deploy')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\William\Desktop\Test Utk Deploy\deploy.py", line 24, in <module>
    newest = max(files , key = os.path.getctime)

  File "C:\Users\William\anaconda3\envs\faceRecog\lib\genericpath.py", line 65, in getctime
    return os.stat(filename).st_ctime

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'Capture.PNG'
```

And so I thought the problem was that my program can't find the latest file (which is indeed Capture.PNG) inside the files array. And then out of curiosity i tried to print the files array

```
print(files)
```

This is the result.

```
['Capture.PNG', 'Screenshot (13).png']
```

According to the result, it seems like  the file Capture.PNG has been successfully stored inside the files array. But when i run the print(max(files , key = os.path.getctime)) code, my program show that error. Can anybody please help? Thanks in advance

Comment: BTW: `endswith` can use tuple `file.lower().endswith( ('.png', ,'.jpg', '.jpeg') )` and you can use `lower()`

Comment: better keep filename with `path` - `os.path.join( path, file )`. You can also create absolute path - `os.path.abspath( os.path.join( path, file ) )`

Answer (score 0):

The module os.path.getctime gets the system’s ctime **of the specified path**. Your list includes only file names and not their full path. When trying to print the time, it will look for the file in the default directory (which might be the directory you called the script from) which is not where the file is actually located.

You can solve this by appending the full directory to the name, something like so:

```
files.append('%s/%s'.format(path,file))
```

Mind you, my knowledge is a little rusty but something like that should work.

Comment: better `os.path.join( path, file )`

Comment: @furas: That would be even better indeed.